# Drawing outline of houses from aerial images

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, gis, arcgis

I am interested to know if it is possible to draw polygons of the outlines of houses and buildings from aerial imagery similar to what is visible on google maps.

[image: example google maps image]

Is this something that can be done through computer vision or neural networks?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done, however, it is ofcourse a topview, so possible veranda's and stuff will also count. Other problems might be some parts of the house being covered by trees or other objects. You can potentially include stuff like doghouses, strange looking cars, fat americans or any other thing which fulfil your programmed criteria (straight edges, color, color differences and other stuff you might want to add)

Ofc the quality of those selfmade maps is a lot worse than those which you can steal from your local government which include all the legal buildings.